# How to define custom API structure for orion context broker?

Tags: fiware-orion

(Moved from https://ask.fiware.org/question/603/how-to-define-custom-api-structure-for-orion-context-broker/)

Can we change definition of API structure to json key/value?

```
{ "temperature": 55, "pressure": 2.2 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NGSIv2, use the `keyValues` mode to achieve that result, e.g.

```
GET /v2/entities?options=keyValues
```

For more information about this (an others) simplified representation modes have a look to the "Simplified Entity Representation" section at the [NGSIv2 specification](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable).